# Different template component in an application

Tags: angular

I'm starting with angular and the next question comes up.

In the component, app.component.html is where I have a navigation and some more elements that are common to all routes. But now I want to create a part of the administrator that has to use neither the navigation nor the other elements. But others that I have created.

My question is: Can I create another file type "app.component" for the administration part with its own structure and that has nothing to do with the other party?

Comment: It would be nice to see some code to provide some assistance

Comment: Your question is a little unclear to me, but to answer. No, you cannot create another file called `app.component`, because your component files need to be unique. However, you can create for example an `administration.component`.

Comment: At any rate, this question demonstrates a lack of knowledge on some very basic concepts with Angular. I would recommend you take a tutorial on the framework to learn the fundamentals. Here is the tutorial provided by the Angular team https://angular.io/tutorial - Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need another "app.component", you probably just want to create another module for admin utilities and routing. That way your app.component is just the parent for the whole application.

app.component will be in the main app.module.ts file, then you can create two child modules that are both imported into the app.module.

**for example**

- app.module.ts (this has no entry components, just generic imports, including the child modules)

  - admin.module.ts

    - various components, directives, and services specific to the admin module
  - user.module.ts (I just picked "user" because it is generic)

    - various components, directives, and services specific to the "user" module

The point is to modularize sections of your application. That way your admin module can live separately from everything else and will not rely on any dependencies that the user.module does. And vice versa.

In addition, this opens up lazy loading options, specialized route guards per module, etc... I recommend reading over [NgModules on the angular docs.](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules)

You'll notice at the end of that doc there are links for different module "types":

- Feature Modules.
- Entry Components.
- Providers.

What you're asking for is two different feature modules with their own entry components and services

Comment: I have created a new module as said for the administrator, but I still take the <router-outlet> </ router-outlet> from app.component.html

Comment: As you should. That is the main app component. Your app.module should include routing that points to both child modules, which should have their own routing too. @jlgf check out angular heroes file structure and how they manage modules. https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-3-wrap-up

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I begin to understand the structure. Would it be convenient to create another module for the login?

Comment: You can technically give everything its own module. So its entirely up to you. Login components and services can easily be decoupled from the rest of the app by using guards on all your authentication required routes. If you do give your login stuff its own module you;ll have to figure out a way to toggle between admin/user urls.